# umzug unable to import an ES module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, mysql2

I am trying to build a simple app as my personal project using ExpressJS. I am using sequelize ORM for handling database changes. Now I want to rollback a migration and to do so i used the following command
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo`
When i run the above command I get stuck with the following error.
[image]

Here  is the content of my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.33.0"
  },
  "type":"module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the content of my sequelize migration file.

```
'use strict';

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */

export default {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add altering commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
     */
    queryInterface.addColumn('Users','deletedAt', {
      type: Sequelize.TIME
    })
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */
    queryInterface.removeColumn('Users','deletedAt')
  }
};
```

I want to use ES6 modules and syntax for my project.
Thanks in advance for all the help I will be receiving.

Comment: “I want to use ES6 modules and syntax for my project” — well the software you are using doesn’t support that. So you can change your mind, hack umzug, submit a patch for umzug, or ask the developers if Umzug to support EXMAScript modules.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Sequelize migration file extension from .js to .mjs and also define a custom resolver in your main script.

For more info, I followed the example here (check out what the .README says): https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/tree/main/examples/2.es-modules

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use the `resolve` function when instantiating the Umzug, so you can use `import` instead of letting Umzug to use `require`.

On the other hand, using `import` is a bit tricky as the `resolve` function must not be `async` while `import` returns a `Promise`. So you need to wrap the `import` in a function (let's say, import caller) and use it in `up` and `down` functions.

```
import { dirname } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

export const migrator = new Umzug({
  migrations: {
    glob: ['migrations/*.{ts,js}', { cwd: __dirname }],
    resolve: params => {
      const getModule = () => import(params.path!);
      return {
        // adjust the parameters Umzug will
        // pass to migration methods when called
        name: params.name,
        up: async (params) => (await getModule()).up(params),
        down: async (params) => (await getModule()).down(params),
      };
    }
  },
  context: sequelize,
  storage: new SequelizeStorage({
    sequelize,
  }),
  logger: console,
});
```